# create Property view rcp

Tags: eclipse, view, properties, rcp

Hi I am new to Eclipse rcp. I am developing a small application. In this application I want to show property view corressponding to the selected file.
I referred to this article : http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Adapters/index.html
However, I am unable to find how to create property view and show it in my application perspective. Like shown here: http://www.eclipsepluginsite.com/properties-2.html

So, instead of eclipse application , it should be my application , my navigator view and my property view.

Answer (score 0):

The Properties view has the id `org.eclipse.ui.views.PropertySheet`, there is a constant for this value `IPageLayout.ID_PROP_SHEET`.

So if you are using a Perspective factory for your RCP then you need to do an `addView` for `IPageLayout.ID_PROP_SHEET` to the main `IPageLayout` or an `IFolderLayout`.

Comment: So I added this id to the IFolderLayout. It didn't worked. So for creating a property view, Do I have to create a  class subclassing Property Sheet?

Comment: I figured it out. I Created a subclass of PropertySheet. Created a view , and from the view point to that subclass. Thank you .